# Identify $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Whats the best way to find out what `$(this)` currently equals in jQuery?

For example `alert(this);` isn't much help.

The reason I ask is that a piece of code is not currently doing what it should do after I have moved the code into a function.

The excerpt below is now in a function, and $(this) now seems to refer to the DOMWindow.

```
if($(this).hasClass('open'))
  {
    alert('I should be closed');
    $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
    $(this).parents('article').css('border', '1px solid red').animate({'width': '212px'}, 100, "linear", function() {
    run_masonry();
    });
  }
  else
  {
    alert('I should be open');
    $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open');
    $(this).parents('article').css('border', '1px solid blue').animate({'width': '646px'}, 100, "linear", function() {
    run_masonry();
  });
}
```

How do I keep it as $(this) being the original clicked element?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Whats the best way to find out what `$(this)` currently equals in jQuery?

By logging it to the console of your favorite javascript debugging tool (like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome developer toolbar for example):

```
console.log($(this));
```

which will return a jQuery wrapped object. If you want to know more about the native object you could use:

```
console.log(this);
```

If you are doing javascript development you should use a javascript debugging tool. `alert` is not such tool.

---

Now that you have updated your question with some code source it seems that you are using `$(this)` in the global scope. Then it will refer to the `window` object. If you want it to refer to some clicked element or something you will have to first subscribe to the .click event:

```
$('.someSelector').click(function() {
    // here $(this) will refer to the original element that was clicked.
});
```

or if you wanted to externalize this code in a separate function:

```
function foo() {
    // here $(this) will refer to the original element that was clicked.
}

$('.someSelector').click(foo);
```

or:

```
function foo(element) {
    // here $(element) will refer to the original element that was clicked.
}

$('.someSelector').click(function() {
    foo(this);
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to narrow it down? that returns a lot of data.

Comment: @CraigWard, yes, use `console.log(this);` to log only the native object and not `$(this)`.

Comment: @CraigWard what would you like to narrow it down to though? I wish it was as `$(this).attributesThatIWantToSee()`

Comment: It is returning DOMWindow, which 100's of children objects. Is this normal?

Comment: @CraigWard, I don't know if it is normal. That will depend on your code and the scoping of the variables. What properties does it have?

Comment: @CraigWard Well then `this` is likely `window` which means you have a function context issue somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

With moving code into a function usually the scope of the code changes. So "this" will no longer refer to the original object but rather to a new one (or the global "window" object). If you show us your code we will be able to identify the problem.

Comment: That sounds like the problem. Its returning the DOMWindow. Is there a way to to keep $(this) when in the function?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you do something like this:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
    clickHandler();
});
```

In this case `clickHandler` will be called in Window object context. To preserve correct context just change your code to:

```
$('#element').click(clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what's being passed around you can use either my version or prinzhorn's version of jquerylog. It should help you identify step by step what's happening:

http://www.jquerylog.com / https://github.com/fmsf/jQueryLog

For a call like:

```
$("#foo").parents(".t1").next().prev().parent().find(".t2:last .t4:last").text("test");
```

You'll get an output like this (which identifies the div in each step:

```
$('#foo'): [<div id="foo" class="t3"></div>]
    parents('.t1'): [ <div class="t1">…</div> ]
        next(undefined): [ <div class="t1">…</div> ]
            prev(undefined): [ <div class="t1">…</div> ]
                parent(undefined): [ <body>…</body> ]
                    find('.t2:last .t4:last'): [<div class="t4">teste</div>]
```